# Architecture Spring MVC: JSP pages to angular JS

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

Currently, I have a small Web site using Spring MVC (controller) with JSP pages.
I would like to migrate JSP pages to AngularJS/HTML but I have some troubles to understand the global picture.

I guess, I should migrate my @Controller to @RestController. These controllers will provide data/JSON necessary to display angularJS/HTML pages. Right ? 
I haven't trouble to create these REST controllers: I can consult JSON data by using URL provided in request mapping of my REST controllers.

My problem is to display index page. In WEB-INF folder, I have an index.html. I would like to access to this page via: http://localhost/MyApp/
How should I process ?

A) Do I need a @Controller with request mapping on '/' which return 'index' view ? Then, the index.html will in charge to call REST controllers thanks to AngularJS ?

B) Should I disable all @Controller on server side and the index.html should be directly the entry point of my Web site ? How configure Spring MVC in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of alternatives and all of them valid. With legacy Jspx MVC projects I do the next:

**Small project**

- Create a package *api* to put on it the REST Controllers. Returns JSON
- Create apackage *web* to put on it the View Controllers.

**Big projects**
Divide into separated projects

- myproject- api. For REST: JSON
- myproject-web. For frontend resources: HTML, CSS, JS

To serve the index.html,as you appointment, you need configure a Controller with a RequestMapping */* that returs "index". The template views and *viewresolver* mades the trick.

From AngularJS I suggest try [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and retrieve views and resourfes according your url state.